# Change Sign-up link of Amazon cognito to Custom URL

Tags: amazon-cognito

I have an application which uses Cognito's hosted UI for login and Signup. I am implementing a functionality wherein I want to update the signup link of cognito hosted UI to a custom URL. Currently, if we click on Signup, it redirects the user to cognito's registration page but I want the user to redirect to some other URL. Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: Does the documentation here meet your needs? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-add-custom-domain.html

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I want to still use cognito's hosted UI for login but have a custom signup page. So, when the user clicks on Signup on the hosted UI, it should be redirected to my custom signup page.

Comment: Did anyone found its solution? @GirlGeek